# routing between linux namespaces

Tags: networking, routing, namespace, network-namespaces

I have the following network topology using linux namespaces:

```
.--------.veth0       .--------.veth2       .--------.
| ns_snd |------------| ns_mid |------------| ns_rcv |
'--------'       veth1'--------'       veth3'--------'
```

veth0: 10.0.0.1/30
veth1: 10.0.0.2/30
veth2: 10.0.0.5/30
veth3: 10.0.0.6/30

veth0 belongs to ns_snd,
veth[1,2] belongs to ns_mid,
veth3 belongs to ns_rcv

The commands are:

```
S1="veth0"
S2M1="veth1"
M2R1="veth2"
R1="veth3"

NS_SND="ns_snd"
NS_RCV="ns_rcv"
NS_MID="ns_mid"


#Remove existing namespace
sudo ip netns del $NS_SND
sudo ip netns del $NS_RCV
sudo ip netns del $NS_MID

#Remove existing veth pairs
sudo ip link del $S1
sudo ip link del $R1
sudo ip link del $S2M1
sudo ip link del $M2R1

#Create veth pairs
sudo ip link add $S1 type veth peer name $S2M1
sudo ip link add $M2R1 type veth peer name $R1

#Bring up
sudo ip link set dev $S1 up
sudo ip link set dev $S2M1 up
sudo ip link set dev $M2R1 up
sudo ip link set dev $R1 up


#Create the specific namespaces
sudo ip netns add $NS_SND
sudo ip netns add $NS_RCV
sudo ip netns add $NS_MID

#Move the interfaces to the namespace
sudo ip link set $S1 netns $NS_SND
sudo ip link set $S2M1 netns $NS_MID
sudo ip link set $M2R1 netns $NS_MID
sudo ip link set $R1 netns $NS_RCV

#Configure the loopback interface in namespace
sudo ip netns exec $NS_SND ip address add 127.0.0.1/8 dev lo
sudo ip netns exec $NS_SND ip link set dev lo up
sudo ip netns exec $NS_RCV ip address add 127.0.0.1/8 dev lo
sudo ip netns exec $NS_RCV ip link set dev lo up
sudo ip netns exec $NS_MID ip address add 127.0.0.1/8 dev lo
sudo ip netns exec $NS_MID ip link set dev lo up

#add bridge
#sudo ip netns exec $NS_MID brctl addbr br549
#sudo ip netns exec $NS_MID brctl addif br549 $S2M1
#sudo ip netns exec $NS_MID brctl addif br549 $M2R1
#sudo ip netns exec $NS_RCV ip route add 10.0.0.0/30 via 10.0.0.5

#Bring up interface in namespace
sudo ip netns exec $NS_SND ip link set dev $S1 up
sudo ip netns exec $NS_SND ip address add 10.0.0.1/30 dev $S1
sudo ip netns exec $NS_MID ip link set dev $S2M1 up
sudo ip netns exec $NS_MID ip address add 10.0.0.2/30 dev $S2M1
sudo ip netns exec $NS_MID ip link set dev $M2R1 up
sudo ip netns exec $NS_MID ip address add 10.0.0.5/30 dev $M2R1
sudo ip netns exec $NS_RCV ip link set dev $R1 up
sudo ip netns exec $NS_RCV ip address add 10.0.0.6/30 dev $R1

#Add ip routes
sudo ip netns exec $NS_SND ip route add 10.0.0.4/30 via 10.0.0.2
sudo ip netns exec $NS_RCV ip route add 10.0.0.0/30 via 10.0.0.5

#sudo ip netns exec $NS_SND "./scripts/setup_ns_snd.sh"
#sudo ip netns exec $NS_RCV "./scripts/setup_ns_rcv.sh"
```

Inside ns_snd I can ping 10.0.0.5, but 10.0.0.6 not. What do I need to add or what I have forgotten to add?

Comment: The first thing I'd fix is the overlapping subnets. `$NS_MID` and `$NS_RCV` are both using `10.0.0.4/30`, which is `10.0.0.4-10.0.0.7`.

Comment: @Patrick they both have interfaces on that subnet, so they should both have addresses in the range.

Comment: Ah, ok, I see what you're doing. I didn't read your script thoroughly enough.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The issue is that you're trying to route a packet from namespace `ns_snd` through `ns_mid` to `ns_rcv`. The kernel is going to treat the namespaces as if they were separate hosts. Meaning you have to configure the kernel to act as a router.
This is rather simple to do:

```
sudo ip netns exec $NS_MID sysctl -w net.ipv4.ip_forward=1
```

Comment: Thanks. This post is also helpful: https://yakking.branchable.com/posts/networking-4-namespaces-and-multi-host-routing/